# How to do "Two 301 Redirects to One 301 Redirect" Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, url-rewriting, redirect

## I need one 301 redirect on Wordpress site not twice

i need https://www.example.com/sports/test/index.php -> https://www.example.com/sports/test

i have a twice 301 redirect https://www.example.com/sports/test/index.php -> https://www.example.com/sports/test/ -> https://www.example.com/sports/test

I have a site on Wordpress with structure http://www.example.com then i bougth ssl-sertificate and my structure now https://www.example.com 
Settings: 
1) Permalinks -> custom structure https://www.example.com/%category%/%postname%/ 
2) Category prefix -> . (just dot) 
3) .htacess (with Wordpress original rules for urls)

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

#use many recomendation
#-------like this
#RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com [NC]
#RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [L,R=301]
#-------end like this

#-------like this
#RewriteEngine on
#RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [OR]
#RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
#RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.+)$ [NC]
#RewriteRule ^ https://www.%1%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,L,R=301] 
#-------end like this

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]   #remove index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

All it works but with twice 301 redirects or many loop redirects, i need once redirect on WP site. Thank u for helps me )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After **RewriteEngine On** and before **RewriteBase /** adding this lines: 
`RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} !POST` 
`RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} " /(index\.php|([^?]*)/index\.php)"` 
`RewriteRule ^  https://www.example.com/%2 [R=301,L,NE]`

It works fine for me

Answer (score 0):

Try to change permalink structure and resave it.

If .htaccess is wordpress default you should haven't problem.

For https i use this plugin https://it.wordpress.org/plugins/really-simple-ssl/ is very simple to use and efficient.

Let me know

Comment: 1) I resaved many times <br/> .htacess by default after resave permalink structure and i have installed real-simple-ssl plugin <br/> screenshoot http://prntscr.com/nyh1g8